# Bootstrap strange scaling behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I recently deployed the following app: http://radiant-hollows-1943.herokuapp.com/

I used Bootstrap to make sure the website is mobile first. I tested this with chrome on my laptop by resizing the window to smaller sizes where everything works fine: the navbar collapses and the columns wrap.

However, when I visit the website on my mobile phone this does not work. The website just scales to size of the phone (meaning everything gets smaller). The navbar does not collapse and so forth...

It looks like bootstrap is not detecting the screen size on a mobile browser?

I tested this with safari and chrome

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to add this in your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you add that it *should* adjust for mobile viewing.